# SQL Server failover cluster - determine active node

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, cluster-computing, failover

Is there a way to **programmatically determine which node in a SQL Server failover cluster is the active node**? Or at least determine whether the current machine is the active node?

I have a Windows program which runs on both physical nodes in a failover cluster, but that should operate differently depending on whether it is running on the active node. **Part of the reason is that this program should not run simultaneously on the inactive and the active node**.

(I've read a bit about making the program cluster aware, but that seems heavily overkill for this simple scenario.)

Comment: If you're starting to care about the clustering, I think you'd be far better off investing the energy to do it right - what if there's a manual failover initiated between your check and whatever you're planning to do after that? You'd think you're on the active node when that is no longer true.

Comment: @Damien How would you "do it right" in this case?

Comment: really not run simultaneously on the inactive and the active node. ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From SQL Server:

```
Select ServerProperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')
```

You can also access it through the Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo Namespace as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.computernamephysicalnetbios.aspx).

Comment: Can you explain how `Select ServerProperty('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS')` tells you whether you are on the active node or not?

Comment: @Neilw: From the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx): "NetBIOS name of the local computer on which the instance of SQL Server is currently running.
For a clustered instance of SQL Server on a failover cluster, this value changes as the instance of SQL Server fails over to other nodes in the failover cluster.
On a stand-alone instance of SQL Server, this value remains constant and returns the same value as the MachineName property."

Answer (score 0):

You can check like that:

**1. Check Availability Group Status:**

```
if (select
        ars.role_desc
    from sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states ars
    inner join sys.availability_groups ag
    on ars.group_id = ag.group_id
    where ag.name = 'AvailabilityGroupName'
    and ars.is_local = 1) = 'PRIMARY'
begin
    -- this server is the primary replica, do something here
end
else
begin
    -- this server is not the primary replica, (optional) do something here
end
```

*Remember to change AvailabilityGroupName

or

**2. prevent executing job on secondary:**

```
IF master.dbo.svf_AgReplicaState('AvailabilityGroupName')=0  raiserror ('This is not the primary replica.',2,1)
```

or

**3. check write availability on secondary:**

```
IF (SELECT CONVERT(sysname,DatabasePropertyEx(DB_NAME(),'Updateability'))) != 'READ_ONLY'
BEGIN

-- this server is the primary replica, do something here

END
```

or

**4. for SQL2014 and newer:**

```
IF master.dbo.fn_hadr_database_is_primary_replica('Admin') = 1
    BEGIN 
        -- this server is the primary replica, do something here
    END
ELSE 
    BEGIN 
        -- this server is not the primary replica, (optional) do something here
    END
```